# SQL: keep one record from n-records with same foreign key

Tags: sql, sybase

I have some records and want only to keep the lowest (min) number from a customer:

This:

```
Customer | Number
1        | 2
1        | 4
2        | 1
1        | 3
2        | 2
```

should be tranformed via sql to:

```
Customer | Number
1        | 2
2        | 1
```

using Sybase ADS local table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Customer, MIN(Number)
FROM your_table
GROUP BY Customer;
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use `min()` and group by the `customer`:

```
select customer, min(number)
from yourtable
group by customer
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5ae3b/2)